# Magento 2 : Image is not showing on product detail page after few seconds

Tags: magento2, product, product-images

[image]

Product image is not showing after few seconds on product detail page. When page loads it showing the image but after few seconds it's vanishing.

Please provide any solution you have.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This not at all Magento 2 problem.
you can use this css to your file and then run `static-content:deploy`

```
.product.media{
    display: block;
}
```

By default bootstrap media use `display:flex;`
This is the main problem for not showing the image.